# How to get current active window while running my java application

Tags: java, swing

I need to get current active window.
I have used `KeyboardFocusManager`, for getting active window. But i am getting active window is null.
below is the code.
please provide any way to get current active window.

```
KeyboardFocusManager currentManager = KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager();  
Window activeWindow = currentManager.getActiveWindow();
```

Comment: You're talking about Java windows or also native?

Comment: Yes i am taking about java windows.

Comment: *"I need to get current active window."* .. why? 1) See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) 2) See also [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Answer (score 11):

This single line of code should work:

```
Window activeWindow = javax.swing.FocusManager.getCurrentManager().getActiveWindow();
```

from the JavaDoc:

> Returns the active Window, **if the active Window is in the same context
>   as the calling thread**. Only a Frame or a Dialog can be the active
>   Window. The native windowing system may denote the active Window or its
>   children with special decorations, such as a highlighted title bar.
>   The active Window is always either the focused Window, or the first
>   Frame or Dialog that is an owner of the focused Window.

to get the **GlobalActiveWindow**, call:

```
 javax.swing.FocusManager.getCurrentManager().getGlobalActiveWindow();
```

JavaDoc:

> Returns the active Window, even if the calling thread is in a different context than the active Window. Only a Frame or a Dialog can be the active Window. The native windowing system may denote the active Window or its children with special decorations, such as a highlighted title bar. The active Window is always either the focused Window, or the first Frame or Dialog that is an owner of the focused Window.

**Note:**
When your application does not have the focus, this method returns null!

Cheers!

Comment: It gives me `null` while I use calc process.
P.S. I use `java.awt.*` in Intellij IDE in Windows.

Comment: Great! But it says it has protected access in java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.

Answer (score 1):

Found the following code and it worked fine for me:

```
Window getSelectedWindow(Window[] windows) {
    Window result = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < windows.length; i++) {
        Window window = windows[i];
        if (window.isActive()) {
            result = window;
        } else {
            Window[] ownedWindows = window.getOwnedWindows();
            if (ownedWindows != null) {
                result = getSelectedWindow(ownedWindows);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

And you can call it like this using the `static` method of class `Window`:

```
Window w = getSelectedWindow(Window.getWindows());
```

Good Luck.

Almost forgot to mention, I've found the recursive method in [this](http://www.rojotek.com/blog/2004/10/27/code-snippit-to-find-the-active-window-in-swing/) site.